# Icons In Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, icons, android-appcompat, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm fooling around with collapsing toolbar. Everything seems good. But My icons are not centered with the title. I think that's because of `fitsSystemWindows()`. But at the same time images are not covering the status bar. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Java Code :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shr___add__vehicle);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.add_vehicle_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout appbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_vehicle_collapse);
    appbar.setTitle("My Bikes");
    appbar.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#F05329"));
```

XML :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.techindyeah.soherides.SHR_Activity_Add_Vehicle">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_vehicle_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/add_vehicle_collapse"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rl_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/bikeimage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/add_vehicle_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_shr__activity__add__vehicle" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_vehicle_insert_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/add_vehicle_app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_insert_photo_white_24dp" />
```

This is what I have now : 
  [Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J61mE.jpg) 
  [Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeDxO.png)

Comment: post your image that you want to.. also your code...

Comment: your arrow is placed at correct place.. where you want to place this?

Comment: This is what I want. Mine doesn't look like this.

Comment: hows your image looks like and also paste your xml code... there is some problem in your xml... which support library are you using

Comment: Right top icon in menu... just add menu in your activity it will shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As per my knowledge back arrow does not move, you can hide it while scrolling if you want.

2) To add Option to right side of toolbar you can use `menu.xml`

menu.xml

```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_map"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
      android:title="@string/action_map"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:orderInCategory="1" />
```

in Java file

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_map) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: you can add more items through menu.xml if you want and handle visibility using `android:showAsAction`

Comment: Just fr information. Is it possible to add icons horizontally in title bar. Side by side? If yes. Just give me an idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks alot. That was easy. Now the only thing is, its not in centred with the title. Can you please look at the code. I have added more details in my question above. Thanks again!

Comment: @AbhishekKumar could you just add the updated image to get clear view.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, the issue is your `toolbar` is going below status bar.

Comment: Also you can set it globally by setting in the theme as <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

Comment: Fixed! Thanks alot!

Comment: @AbhishekKumar you can accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` and `app:layout_behavior` in your arrow image 
and use

```
ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```